# What are the best practices to convert an Objective C project to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to partially carry an Objective C project to Swift. I look for the best practices.

Should I start with Modal Classes or where should I start? Also This project is an open project, the other developers use and develops the project.

Comment: Are you aware that you can use both ObjC and Swift _at the same time_? There is no need to convert from ObjC to Swift.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that and I want to carry partially.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by carry partially?

Comment: I want to carry the project step by step, firstly modals, then views. I am asking how could it be easier or if somebody did it, how he/she did?

Comment: As far as I know, this is quite pointless since projects can be bilingual. What benefits does converting an existing project to Swift give you?

Comment: @Sweeper As for your question "What benefits does converting an existing project to Swift give you?": The benefit is when you want your developers to continue developing on the project and want to do so in Swift. Development does not mean just adding new files which will be in Swift. Existing code might need modification, refactor, optimization... In this case you may port that specific class... and then another class... and another... Or try to port as much as possible in reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

**If you really must do this then let's look at some facts:**

You will need to be converting code basically file by file. When a file is converted into Swift it will no longer be usable by Objective-C unless you specify it to be. You don't want to specify it because you will not need it at the end when the whole code is migrated so you should avoid working on the same file twice.

Every Objective-C file can be used by Swift by simply adding its header into bridging header.

Some code might change substantially when porting to Swift such as enumerations and class nesting though this is not mandatory at least in first phase.

**How to go about realizing it:**

You should start with classes, files and modules which are least used by other parts of your project. It seems for `iOS` applications that would be starting with view controllers.

After you are done with those most straight forward classes you might want to start breaking your project down to groups where each group is as closed as possible and used as least by other groups as possible. At this point you will need to migrate the whole group altogether for the procedure to work.

So first for each screen and then for each group you will be able to commit and push your changes so other developers may continue working on the project.

**Just some thoughts:**

If this is a project that is still in development then you should probably exclude modules that will most likely never be modified. There is no benefit of porting a well written code, port only the code you wish to continue developing and wish to do it in Swift.

Still once you convert the whole project the target logic may be way different then it was in Objective-C. Working with arrays, dictionaries, `NSNumber`, typecasting will most likely be quite a pain to migrate (depending on how you are using these now). But even after migration you might come up with ineffective code unless you completely restructure your code to be Swift friendly.